# Missing all resource styles in Android Studio, accidentally deleted - AAPT2 error: check logs for details

Tags: java, android, gradle, aapt2

I accidentally deleted all of the style resources from Android Studio.. I tried "undo" right away and I tried looking in the history.. I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling the sdks that I have, but from what I can tell, the issue is Gradle. I then tried downloading Gradle 4.10 but I'm not sure what I'm doing. (Still learning!) I have a project due and I really need to fix this! I'm including a screenshot of all the issues I can get on one screen. Since I haven't found anything even close to answering my question, I thought it'd be a good idea to post. I'm also going to paste some error text from further down, just to give an idea of how bad I messed up, in case it contains any clues... Thanks so much in advance!

```
[AAPT2 Error, org.gradle.initialization.ReportedException: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:139)][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqGQ9.jpg

(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:45)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try creating a new XML, copying the styles from another project, editing and see if it fixes?

Comment: I tried making a new project and opening up an old one that used to work. I’m missing TabLayout as well... it can’t find them in the program at all, from what I can tell.

Comment: Check the Graddle to see if there's conflict with dependencies. Maybe you're using something in your Layout without implementing it in Graddle. Check the layout as well. Check folder values, see if styles.xml is ok. Come back here and report.

Comment: I checked everything as well as I knew how to check, and still nothing stood out. I reinstalled Android Studio hoping that would solve it, nope. I dropped my sdk down to 26 and that seemed to solve my problem. So it is something to do with 27... I still have the issue with compiling and viewing the preview as I build in 28 so I guess I will have to stick with 26 for now?